# video.js player video is black

Tags: video.js

I have a very strange problem with video-js-4.12.5. I'm using ffmpeg on a fedora 20 machine to send a live stream up to my vps which then webcasts it out. The following command on the fedora machine works fine, the stream plays in vlc fine, and the web page on the vps also displays the video fine:

```
ffmpeg -i [input] blah-de-blah 'rtmp://vps-server'
```

Going back to the fedora machine I'd also like to record the video to mp4 file as well as stream it. The following command works fine however it produces a black video image in the web page. The command runs fine on the fedora machine, in vlc I get a proper image as well but on the web page the video is black. I do get audio but no video.

```
ffmpeg -i [input] blah-de-blah 'recording.mp4|[f=flv]rtmp://vps-server'
```

Does anyone know why this would be? The problem is definitely in the video.js player or on the vps somewhere. This is the code on the web page that plays the video:

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" preload="auto" width="660" height="500"
      poster="video-poster.gif"
      data-setup="{}">
     <source src="rtmp://<vps.svr.ip>:1936/live/livestream1" type='rtmp/mp4' />
    <track kind="captions" src="demo.captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English"></track>
    <track kind="subtitles" src="video/js/demo.captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English"></track>
  </video>
```

this has got me baffled so thanks for any pointers.

Comment: You might want to check the codecs used. In VLC you can see that under `Window>Media Information`.

Comment: I discovered that the problem lay in the web player itself and not where I was originally looking. The image did appear in vlc when I double checked it so ffmpeg was working fine I would like to mark this thread as solved or closed but I'm find it impossible to do....